# How to display elements of a Many-To-Many relation in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have following models:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('topic')
        verbose_name_plural = _('topics')

class TopicLabel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    order = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    def getTopics():
        return TopicLabelConnection.objects.filter(labelId=self.id).orderby('order')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class TopicLabelConnection(models.Model):
    topicId = models.ForeignKey(Topic, related_name='connection_topic')
    labelId = models.ForeignKey(TopicLabel, related_name='connection_label')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.labelId.name + ' / ' + self.topicId.title
```

There are

- *Topics*,
- *TopicLabels* and
- connections between them (*TopicLabelConnection*).

One label can be assigned to many topics.

I want to display an ordered list with following structure:

1. Label 1

   1. Topic 1
   2. Topic 2
   3. Topic 3
2. Label 2

   1. Topic 4
   2. Topic 5
   3. Topic 6

where topics 1, 2 and are assigned to label 1 and topics 4, 5 and 6 - to label 2.

In order to do this, I created view function and HTML template fragment shown below.

**View function**

```
def home(request):      
    labels = TopicLabel.objects.filter(connection_label__isnull=False).distinct().order_by('order')

    return TemplateResponse(request, 'home.tpl.html', locals())
```

**Template fragment**

```
<ol>
    {% for cur_label in labels %}
        <li>{{ cur_label.name }}</li>
        <ol>
        {% for cur_topic_label_connection in cur_label.getTopics %}
            <li>{{ cur_topic_label_connection.topicId.title }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ol>
    {% endfor %}    
</ol>
```

The result: Only the labels are displayed, but not their topics.

How should I change the code in order for both the labels and the topics to be displayed in the hiearchical list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a proper ManyToMany field:

```
class TopicLabel(models.Model):
    ...
    topics = models.ManyToManyField(Topic, through=TopicLabelConnection)
```

Now your `getTopics` method can be removed, and in the template you can just do:

```
{% for topic in cur_label.topics.all %}
    <li>{{ topic.title }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Note that the `order_by` call in `getTopics` makes no sense, because the only model that has an `order` field is TopicLabel, but you're trying to get topics, which has no order field.

Comment: Thanks. Now a really stupid question - how can I define `ManyToManyField(..., through=TopicLabelConnection)` without getting errors like `NameError: name 'TopicLabelConnection' is not defined`? `TopicLabel` and `TopicLabelConnection` reference each other.

Comment: Change TopicLabelConnection . Use the string 'TopicLabelConnection' instead.     topics = models.ManyToManyField(Topic, through='TopicLabelConnection')

Comment: I figured it out - the `through` argument needs to be put in single quotes (`topics = models.ManyToManyField(Topic, through='TopicLabelConnection')`).

Comment: If TopicLabelConnection has no attributes at all, it can be removed (along with the through kword)

Answer (score 1):

You aren't properly filtering.

The problem is in the getTopics method

Try this instead:

```
return TopicLabelConnection.objects.filter(labelId__id=self.id).order_by('order')
```

Notice labelId is a TopicLabel, not its id

Comment: Probably, you should use the related-names. Try removing them to see if that's the problem. I can't think of something else, sorry